# Select MAX between 2 similar ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select maximum number of wins from many teams
Table looks like-

```
NAME WINS  LOSES    ID_TEAM


Gordon  4     0        5 

Garry   7     0        5 

Uldis   5     7        2  

Armands 9     2        2 

Bjorn   12    2        8 

Erwin   1     0        8
```

I tried to select max wins from team 1 but it select booth teammate

```
select max(wins) as max_wins from (select wins from fighter where id_team=1) group by wins;
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Note that we need sample data and _matching_ expected result. You say you want result for team 1, but your sample data has no rows with that id.

Answer (score 2):

getting the `max()` win of same team.

```
select ID_TEAM, max(wins) 
from fighter 
where ID_TEAM = 1
group by ID_TEAM
```

selecting multiple teams, use `IN`keyword

```
select * from fighter f
inner join (
    select ID_TEAM, max(wins) 
    from fighter 
    where ID_TEAM in (1,5,6)
    group by ID_TEAM) t1 on t1.ID_TEAM = f.ID_TEAM
```

Comment: But what if i want to select from multiple team, not one

Comment: use `ID_TEAM in (1, 5, 2)`

Comment: what if i want to select their names to, with adding name in your example select ID_TEAM, max(wins),name 
from fighter 
where ID_TEAM in (1,5,6)
group by ID_TEAM

he will select all name with their numbers of wins

Comment: there, i have updated the 2nd query to include other fields.

Comment: still selecting all fighters

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `analytical` function considering that there may be a case where maximum fights are won by multiple fighters and also the following query will give all the details of the fighter who won maximum games in his team.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.*,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID_TEAM
                ORDER BY
                    WINS DESC NULLS LAST
            ) AS RN
        FROM
            FIGHTER T
        WHERE
            ID_TEAM = 1
    ) -- IF YOU WANT TO GET DATA FOR ALL THE TEAMS THEN REMOVE THIS WHERE CLAUSE
WHERE
    RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is often the most efficient method:

```
select f.*
from fighter f
where f.wins = (select max(f2.wins)
                from fighter f2
                where f2.id_team = f.id_team
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `fighter(id_team, wins)`.